# Rails 4 - switch/change table name during request dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Based on my request, I would like to query either `test_users` or `users`. I am doing this using `User.table_name = "test_users"` or `User.table_name = "users"`

This works in development, but not in production (i.e table name in the query does not change), due to -

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.eager_load = true
```

I am guessing the table names are being cached somewhere and `Model.table_name=` does not update the cache.

How can I switch the table name dynamically? I am running `4.2.0` and if it helps postgres (pg gem).

Comment: I have same problem.Did you find a solution ?